# How do I use JBossAS 5 with Apache Ivy?

Tags: jboss, ivy

I am relitively new to Apache Ivy and am trying to move an existing dev project to using Ivy for dependency management.  The last dependency I have to configure is jboss-javaee.jar.  I can't find it anywhere and am getting the following error message when running

[ivy:retrieve] :: problems summary ::
[ivy:retrieve] :::: WARNINGS
[ivy:retrieve]      module not found: org.jboss#jboss-javaee;5.0.1.GA
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== local: tried
[ivy:retrieve]    C:\Documents and Settings\eweibust.ivy2/local/org.jboss/jboss-javaee/5.0.1.GA/ivys/ivy.xml
[ivy:retrieve]    -- artifact org.jboss#jboss-javaee;5.0.1.GA!jboss-javaee.jar:
[ivy:retrieve]    C:\Documents and Settings\eweibust.ivy2/local/org.jboss/jboss-javaee/5.0.1.GA/jars/jboss-javaee.jar
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== shared: tried
[ivy:retrieve]    C:\Documents and Settings\eweibust.ivy2/shared/org.jboss/jboss-javaee/5.0.1.GA/ivys/ivy.xml
[ivy:retrieve]    -- artifact org.jboss#jboss-javaee;5.0.1.GA!jboss-javaee.jar:
[ivy:retrieve]    C:\Documents and Settings\eweibust.ivy2/shared/org.jboss/jboss-javaee/5.0.1.GA/jars/jboss-javaee.jar
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== public: tried
[ivy:retrieve]    http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/jboss-javaee/5.0.1.GA/jboss-javaee-5.0.1.GA.pom
[ivy:retrieve]    -- artifact org.jboss#jboss-javaee;5.0.1.GA!jboss-javaee.jar:
[ivy:retrieve]    http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/jboss-javaee/5.0.1.GA/jboss-javaee-5.0.1.GA.jar
[ivy:retrieve]      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve]      ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[ivy:retrieve]      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve]      :: org.jboss#jboss-javaee;5.0.1.GA: not found
[ivy:retrieve]      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

```
<dependency org="org.jboss" name="jboss-javaee" rev="5.0.1.GA">
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To update @AngerClown's comment: The current JBoss repository has a different URL.

```
<ibiblio
    name="jboss"
    m2compatible="true"
    root="https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public"
    pattern="[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]" />
```

I found an overview [here](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/index.html#view-repositories;public).

Answer (score 5):

You need to be using the jboss repository at http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/. Use the following as your ivy-settings.xml

```
<ivysettings>
  <settings defaultResolver="myChain" checkUpToDate="true" />
  <resolvers>
    <chain name="myChain">
      <ibiblio name="jboss" m2compatible="true" root="http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/" />
      <ibiblio name="ibiblio" m2compatible="true" />
    </chain>
  </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

The depency needs to look like this aswell:

```
<dependency org="org.jboss.javaee" name="jboss-javaee" rev="5.0.1.GA" />
```

Comment: This works, but if you are using IvyDE with Eclipse and want the sources and javadoc attached, you need to use the following resolver config:
 <ibiblio name="jboss" m2compatible="true" root="http://repository.jboss.org/maven2" pattern="[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]" />
(from http://www.jboss.org/feeds/post/managing_the_dependencies_of_a_seam_gen_project_with_ivy)

Also, in Preferences -> Ivy -> Classpath, add 'sources' to the Sources types entries (mine is now source,src,sources) and '-sources' to Sources suffixes (-source,-sources,-src).

Comment: It took me a bit to figure out that ivy-settings.xml is a file that is referenced by your build.xml (<ivy:settings file="ivysettings.xml"/>).  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195393/where-do-you-put-ivysettings-xml