# where do you put ivysettings.xml?

Tags: ant, ivy

I'm trying to learn how to use ivy and would like to setup a local repository of the .jar files I've downloaded.

Where do you put the [ivysettings.xml](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/trunk/tutorial/defaultconf.html) file? Does it go in the ant library directory?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you'll allow me to clarify, the `ivysettings.xml` is the configuration of your development environment as a whole. It is *not* related to the repository items themselves. Generally speaking, `ivysettings.xml` should sit alongside your main `build.xml`, so that when you put

```
<ivy:settings file="ivysettings.xml"/>
```

in your `build.xml`, it just finds it in the current directory.

This file is completely distinct from the `ivy.xml` files that describe the various modules in your repository. These sit alongside the published artifacts in the repo.

Comment: And what if I have a share ivysettings.xml file retrieved from a server and I want to adjust some more settings (in other words add some stuff to the ivysettings.xml or simply load one more settings file and override the former one)?

Answer (score 1):

You can place your `ivysettings.xml` file anywhere you want and you simply reference it in your Ant script with:

```
<ivy:settings file="ivysettings.xml"/>
```

If you are developing several projects, you will notice that you typically use the same `ivysettings.xml` file everywhere and there's no point in copy/pasting this file manually.

What I do is define one `ivysettings.xml` file that is checked out by all my other projects using `svn:externals`.

Comment: Sorry - bit lost by that... where do I save the ivysettings.xml file, and how do I reference that in terms of Ivy?

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same fun with this toady, and have found you can put the ivysettings.xml file anywhere you like, but you simply reference this location on the commandline when you come to use it. e.g. You can call Ivy from NAnt something like this:

```xml
<exec program="java" 
  commandline=" ... ...  
  -jar [location of .jar file] 
  -settings [location of ivysettings.xml file]
  ... ..." 
/>
```

(where ... means something uninteresting has been removed to save space)

Reference:

- [ivy settings doc](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings.html)